# Set DNS for all wifi networks on ios

Tags: dns, ios, ipad, opendns

I'm trying to set DNS to use Open DNS on an IPad. The [instructions](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228008947-IOS-11-Configuration-for-OpenDNS#:%7E:text=Changing%20your%20IOS%20device%20DNS%20settings%3A%201%20From,...%207%20Tap%20Save%20to%20exit%20the%20menu.)   I have show setting it for a specific wifi network.  I have it set on my home wifi. I'd like it on all networks that the iPad connects to.

Thanks

Comment: well, there is a reason DNS server addresses are connection-specific. I suspect that you will not find a means to do this, unless you can use a local proxy for DNS (somthing like privoxy from back in the day) that can be configured to intercept all traffic, and send DNS requests to arbitrary servers. what you want to do breaks many scenarios that modern OSes are designed to support, and while they may not be valuable to you specifically, it means you're basically fighting against the way the system is designed to work.

Comment: Looks like https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dnscloak-secure-dns-client/id1452162351 will allow me to create blacklists and whitelists which is the main thing I was looking for.